# Google Apps Script how to add event listeners to each checkbox in a group of checkboxes that all have same name

Tags: html, checkbox, google-apps-script, web-applications, addeventlistener

I have a few checkboxes being created dynamically from a server-side callback function in google apps script. The checkboxes are created all with the same name "flavors". I can't seem to figure out how to addEventListener to each checkbox and have it function when the checkbox state is changed. If the checkbox is checked, i'd like to display some items, if it's not, i simply will hide the div for the display items.

How can i add the eventlisteners dynamically the same way i'm adding the checkboxes dynamically?

I've tried checkbox.addEventListener within the function that is creating the checkboxes dynamically, before and after appending the checkbox (see provided code). I've also tried making a function called addEventListeners(), which would just grab all elements by name using .getElementsByName(Name), then looping through each of the checkboxes and adding the event listener. Also tried changing it from "change" to "click" with no luck.

I always want the function displayFlavBlocks(chkboxID) to be run anytime any of the checkboxes are checked or unchecked (anytime the state of the checkbox changes).

html (heavily edited down):

```
<script>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(

          function (flavors) 
           {                         
             var div = document.getElementById("flavorOptions");

             for (var i=0; i<flavors.length; i++) 
             {
              var checkbox = document.createElement("input");                          
              var chkboxValue = flavors[i];
              var chkboxId = "f" + (i+1);

                 checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                 checkbox.name = "flavors";
                 checkbox.value = chkboxValue;
                 checkbox.id = chkboxId;                             

                 div.appendChild(checkbox);

  // set each flavor checkbox to be checked by default
                 document.getElementById(chkboxId).checked = true;
             }
            addEventListeners();             
           }
        ).getBatchFlavs();
      };

function addEventListeners() {

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("flavors");

   for (var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
    { 
     var chkboxId = checkboxes[i].id;

 checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId));
    }
}
```

function displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId) {

var checked = document.getElementById(chkboxId).checked;

```
if (checked)
{    
  if (chkboxId == "f1")
   {
    document.getElementById("f1block").style.display = "block";
    // do some other stuff         
   }
}
```

}

```
</script>
```

The checkbox and label comes up perfectly on the dialog, and it is checked by default. But clicking and unclicking the checkbox does nothing. I checked by printing to console, and see that it prints that the state of the checkbox is true when the dialog first loads, then when i uncheck the checkbox, nothing is printed to the console and nothing happens (i've tested printing a couple things using innerHTML, and nothing gets printed when checking or unchecking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about your whole script, I think that in your script, `displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId)` of `checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId));` run the function of `displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId)`. So how about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId));
```

#### To:

```
checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks);
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the checked ID and value, how about using this sample script? About this, please modify this for your situation.

  ```
  function displayFlavBlocks(chkbox) {
    console.log(chkbox.target.id)
    console.log(chkbox.target.checked)
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

### Edit:

- Checkboxes are added when `google.script.run` is run.
- you want to retrieve the checkbox ID when the checkbox is changed.

I could understand like above from your question and reply comments. And when your additional script is modified, it become as follows. Please modify the functions of `addEventListeners()` and `displayFlavBlocks()` as follows.

#### Modified script:

By following modification, when `google.script.run` is run, the checkboxes are added. After this, when the checkbox is changed, the checkbox ID is retrieved by `obj.target.id`. For example, in the case of your script, when the checkbox of ID of `f1`is changed, the style becomes `block`.

```
function addEventListeners() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("flavors");
  console.log(checkboxes)
  for (var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){ 
    // var chkboxId = checkboxes[i].id; // Modified
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks); // Modified
  }
}

function displayFlavBlocks(obj) { // Modified
  var chkboxId = obj.target.id; // Added
  var checked = document.getElementById(chkboxId).checked;
  if (checked) {    
    if (chkboxId == "f1") {
//      document.getElementById("f1block").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";
      // do some other stuff
    }
  }
}
```

- In the script you are showing in your question, the ID of `f1block` cannot be used. When you want to use ID by `checkbox.id = chkboxId`, it is `f1`.

Comment: but you said to change it to displayFlavBlocks not displayFlavBlocks(chkbox)? i'm confused...  i won't know which checkbox was checked/unchecked unless i dynamically send the chkboxId to my displayFlavBlocks function when the event happens, right?

Comment: @theunspeakablethings Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your script, when ``checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId));`` is run, ``displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId)`` is directly run. By this, the event cannot be registered.

Comment: @theunspeakablethings So in order to register the function of `displayFlavBlocks` as the event, I proposed the modification from `displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId)` to `displayFlavBlocks`. By this, when the checkbox is modified, `displayFlavBlocks` is run, and the event object can be retrieved at the function. Then you can retrieve the checkbox ID and value with `chkbox.target.id` and `chkbox.target.checked` of `displayFlavBlocks(chkbox)`. If I misunderstood your question, please tell me.

Comment: thank you also for your replies! so do i make another function called displayFlavBlocks(chkbox)? how do i know what "chkbox" is?

Comment: @theunspeakablethings Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. When `checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks);` is run in the for loop, the events are added for the function `displayFlavBlocks`. By this, when the checkbox is changed, you can retrieve the checkbox ID and value with the function `function displayFlavBlocks(chkbox) {console.log(chkbox.target.id);console.log(chkbox.target.checked);}`.

Comment: @theunspeakablethings You want to dynamically add the events using `addEventListener` when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(do something).getBatchFlavs()` is run. And your current issue is that the event cannot be dynamically added and you cannot retrieve the checkbox ID even when the checkbox is changed. I understood like this. In order to avoid the issue, I proposed the modification point of `addEventListener`. If I misunderstood what you want to do, please tell me.

Comment: i want to dynamically add the listeners to each checkbox, not the events themselves. when an event does occur, i'd like to send the checkbox ID to the displayFlavBlocks function, or somehow know which checkbox the event occured on.

Comment: @theunspeakablethings Can you provide the script of `displayFlavBlocks`?

Comment: @theunspeakablethings And then, can I ask you about the issue of the modification from `checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId));` to `checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks);`?

Comment: just updated code in original post to include short version of function displayFlavBlocks(chkboxId). yes please do ask, thank you

Comment: @theunspeakablethings Thank you for updating it. I added the modified script. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: it works! thank you! so what exactly is "obj" and where does it come from? and how/why is it just assumed to be passed to displayFlavBlocks function as an argument? if there is a link to read to understand this better, i would really appreciate it. thank you again

Comment: @theunspeakablethings Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When `checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", displayFlavBlocks)` is used, `displayFlavBlocks` is added as an event. When the even is fired (in this case, the checkbox is changed.), `displayFlavBlocks` is run. At that time, an event object is given as the argument. You can retrieve it by `obj` of `displayFlavBlocks(obj)`. The reference is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener .

Comment: ok i think i'm understanding. do you happen to know why the label for each checkbox is not clickable now?

Comment: @theunspeakablethings About `do you happen to know why the label for each checkbox is not clickable now?`, from your script, I cannot understand about the issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. And also, I think that this is new question. So can you post it as new question by including the script for replicating your issue? By this, users including me can think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue. I'm glad.

Comment: i figured it out! i had accidentally moved the line to append the label below appending a space. thank you for all your help.

Comment: @theunspeakablethings Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new issue was also resolved. Thank you for letting me know.